# Dynamic LINQ select clause

Tags: linq, select, if-statement, linq-to-sql, dynamic-linq

I'm using Dynamic LINQ to SQL and also to objects in my application. I have googled around for a solution similar to a sql case, such as the one below.

```
SELECT case when [var] = 'Foo' then 'A' when [var] = 'Bar' then 'B' end
FROM [db].[dbo].[Table]
WHERE 1=1
```

If have tried with IF(condition,true,false) like the below but without success.

```
var query = db.Table.AsQueryable().Where("1==1")
.Select("new(IF(var==\"Foo\",\"A\",\"B\") as TestVar)");
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but i think you should try the following:

```
var query = db.Table.AsQueryable().Where("1==1")
.Select("new(var==\"Foo\" ? \"A\" : var==\"Bar\" ? \"B\" : null as TestVar)");
```

I don't know what are the rules for escaping string in dynamic LINQ, but it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: That may work. I tried the following: var query = db.Budget.AsQueryable().Where("BudgetID == 4 Or BudgetID == 3").Select("new(BudgetID==3 ? 3 : 4) as TestVar"); It complains on "Additional information: Expression is missing an 'as' clause" though :/

Comment: @JohanLarsson I've edited my answear. I think you should move the ')' behind 'as TestVar'

Comment: Now it worked fine. Thank you:) `var query =db.Budget.AsQueryable().Where("BudgetID == 4 Or BudgetID == 3").Select("new(Description==\"Budget 2013\" ? \"its 2k13\" : Description==\"Budget 2014\" ? \"its 2k14\" : null as TestVar)");`